# unable to understand the usage of ternary operator

Tags: c++

Someone posted this as a solution and I am unable to understand it as a whole, but especially the while loop. 
The question is that I have an array of `n` digits, and I have to print the number of times the greatest element of the array appears.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int c, n, max = 0;
    std::cin.ignore();
    while(std::cin >> n)
        max < n ? c = !!(max = n) : c += max == n;
    std::cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Double logical NOT it's a trick to convert value to `bool`, if you about it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone has tried to make this code as short as possible. That is rarely a good goal for a program. We can unpick the code step by step to get back to something more reasonable.

First the ternary operator `max < n ? c = !!(max = n) : c += max == n;` can be converted to:

```
if (max < n) {
    c = !!(max = n);
} else {
    c += max == n;
}
```

`c = !!(max = n);` is a "clever" way of setting `c` to 1 and max to `n` at the same time (though it'll fail if `n` is `0`), this can be rewritten as:

```
max = n;
c = 1;
```

Lastly `c += max == n` is a "clever" way of only incrementing `c` when `max == n` alternatively:

```
if (max == n){
    c++;
}
```

In summary the body of the while loop would be:

```
if (max < n) {
    max = n;
    c = 1;
} else if (max == n){
    c++;
}
```

In real code, readability leads to future maintainability, if somebody showed me this code at work I'd get them to rewrite it. There is no benefit to making code shorter (obviously unless it contains unnecessary operations and can be simplified) and in some cases can actually hamper compiler optimisations.

Comment: "`c = !!(max = n);` is a "clever" way of setting `c` to 1 ...", - 
Generally, `c` can also be set to 0 as well.

Comment: @adziri I did say "though it'll fail if n is 0", the intention of the code is to set `c` to 1 but the cleverness has introduced a bug

Comment: @3Dave as long as the code all fits into a single statement nothing else matters, welcome to the world of competitive programming

Comment: @AlanBirtles I worked with a guy who was convinced that whitespace hurt runtime performance. It was a nightmare.